# Is it possible to freeze multiple rows?

Tags: excel, vba, math, excel-formula, vba7

I would like to freeze multiple rows in the below work sheet so that when I scroll downwards I have the corresponding topics listed below the alphabetical header.

Is this possible and how can I achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can freeze all rows and columns left and above a cell. In order to do that, just select that cell, type `freeze` in the help bar and you'll get the possibility.

E.g. if you select cell "D8" and you press "freeze", then the three most left columns and the first seven rows will be frozen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware how to freeze left and above, what I am searching for is the ability to freeze multiple different rows for example row A, B, C etc. so that when I scroll down each letter replaces the previous one as each row is frozen.

Comment: @Excelnewman: I'm sorry if my answer was not clear: I meant that this is not possible: you can freeze a list of rows and a list of columns, but that will always be the top `x` rows or the top `y` columns, which are all of them adjacent. Freezing non-adjacent rows, like the "A", "B" and "C" in your example, is not possible.